# Access Path variable in Distributed cache

Tags: hadoop, path, mapreduce, distributed-cache

I am trying to access a `Path` variable in Distributed cache.

```
//Job 1
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(MINMAX));
//job 2
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(args[1]));
```

In Driver
`DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path(MINMAX).toUri(),conf);`

and

In setup()

```
Path[] cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(cacheFiles[0])));
```

But showing

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Am I doing anything wrong.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
//Job 1
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(MINMAX));
//job 2
Path prevJob = new Path(new Path(MINMAX), "part-r-[0-9]*");
FileStatus [] list = fs.globStatus(prevJob);
for (FileStatus status : list) {
     DistributedCache.addCacheFile(status.getPath().toUri(), conf);
}
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(args[1]));
```

And access the file in Setup method

```
Path[] cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        fs.open(cacheFiles[0])));
```